# rhandsontable with row highlighting and checkbox columns

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I'm trying to use the `rhandsontable` library to generate a table in which I combine two of the package's nifty features: (1) row highlighting using a customer `renderer` argument, and (2) checkbox column type for a boolean field.

On their own, both features work fine. The below, for example, shows how **row highlighting works**:

```
library(rhandsontable)
df = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

row_highlight = c(5, 7)

rhandsontable(df,
              row_highlight = row_highlight) %>%
hot_cols(renderer = "
  function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

    tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]

    hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
    hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows] 

    if (hrows.includes(row)) {
      td.style.background = 'pink';
    }

    return td;
}")
```

And the below shows how the **checkbox functionality works**:

```
library(rhandsontable)
df = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rhandsontable(df, row_highlight = row_highlight) %>%
  hot_col(col = 'bool', type = 'checkbox')
```

My question: **how do you combine these two features** (ie, generate a table with highlighted rows and functioning checkboxes)?

One would think that the below would work, but the checkboxes don't render (instead showing up as `true` and `false`):

```
library(rhandsontable)
df = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

row_highlight = c(5, 7)

rhandsontable(df,
              row_highlight = row_highlight) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
      function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

        tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]

        hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
        hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows] 

        if (hrows.includes(row)) {
          td.style.background = 'pink';
        }

        return td;
    }") %>%
  hot_col(col = 'bool', type = 'checkbox')
```

[image: Result of failed combination attempt]

Is there a way to combine both checkboxes and row highlighting in a rhandsontable in R?

Answer (score 3):

Different renderers should be applied to columns with *text/numeric* and *logical* variables in order to combine **checkbox functionality and rows highlighting**.

```
library(rhandsontable)
df = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

row_highlight = c(5, 7)

rhandsontable(df,
              row_highlight = row_highlight) %>%
  hot_col(col = names(df)[!names(df) %in% "bool"], 
          renderer = "
          function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
            Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

            tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]

            hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
            hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows] 

            if (hrows.includes(row)) {
              td.style.background = 'pink';
            }

            return td;
          }") %>%
  hot_col(col = "bool",
          renderer = "
          function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
            Handsontable.renderers.CheckboxRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

            tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]

            hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
            hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows] 

            if (hrows.includes(row)) {
              td.style.background = 'pink';
            }

            return td;
          }")
```

[image]